# mongo db how to store multi relation like graph

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, entity-relationship

I have to store some users and their group relations like below

[image]

So I am planning to create a collection like below

UserGroupRelation Collections

```
{
"user":String,
"Group":String"
}
```

example of collections for Super admin users

```
{
"user":"Adminuser-1",
"Group":"Group1"
}


{
"user":"Adminuser-1",
"Group":"Group2"
}

{
"user":"Adminuser-1",
"Group":"Group3"
}
```

where **user & Group** column is indexed and I will run below kind of query

1.Whenever I want to check whether given user has access to the given group

```
db.UserGroupRelation.find(  { user: "Adminuser-1", Group: "Group2"   })
```

2.Also I want to delete all the association whenever we delete group

```
db.UserGroupRelation.deleteMany({  Group: "Group2" })
```

3.Also find all the users of a group

```
 db.UserGroupRelation.find(  { Group: "Group2"   })
```

4.Find Hierarchy?, with my Approach I am not able to find

But with this approach I am duplicating lot of data also in real time I may have 10000 groups and 1 million user so there would be performance issue. And with this I am not able to maintain a hierarchy like **SuperAdmin->SubAdmin->user** of same group

I checked with mongo tree but it is not fitting to this requirement. is there a better way to handle this requirement in mongodb .?

Answer (score 1):

This is the structure your graphic requirements show. It does still lead to repetition though so **you will need to change it**. Read up on [one-many relationships](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/).

```
{
 "superAdmin_ID": "001",
 "groups": [
         {
           "_id": "0",
           "groupNumber": "1",
           "users": [
                      {
                        "_userKey": "1023"
                        "userName": "Fred"
                      },
                      {
                        "_userKey": "1024"
                        "userName": "Steve"
                      }
            ],
            "subAdmin": {
                          "_adminKey": "55230"
                          "adminName": "Maverick"
                        },
         },
         {
           "_id": "1",
           "groupNumber": "2",
           "users": [
                      {
                        "_userKey": "1023"
                        "userName": "Fred"
                      },
                      {
                        "_userKey": "4026"
                        "userName": "Ella"
                      }
            ],
            "subAdmin": {
                          "_adminKey": "55230"
                          "adminName": "Maverick"
                        },
         },
         {
           "_id": "2",
           "groupNumber": "3",
           "users": [
                      {
                        "_userKey": "7026"
                        "userName": "James"
                      }
            ],
            "subAdmin": {
                          "_adminKey": "77780"
                          "adminName": "Chloe"
                        },
         },
  ]
}
```

You can also make subAdmin an array if you need more than one subAdmin within a group.

Comment: Okay, What about if same group contains many users like few thousands, will there be any performance hit though I do index on  userName or userKey.. ?

Comment: In "users" there should only be an array of "_userKey", create seperate array of objects with user details and a matching _userKey if they are in that group. I've never checked the performance of something like this so I can't comment on how it will perform or how to improve. You can write a script that fills the database with that many entries and easily test performance.

Comment: you mean other collection storing userinfo with userKey, actually my question related to index was,  since users is array and will indexing on _userKey works? because users array may contain thousands of value hence, hence writing a query to check given  Group & userKey is a valid will be problem ?